# Call Azure function from Dynamics 365 using oauth2

Tags: dynamic, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming

I've been searching about call an Azure function from CRM using ouath2, all the information that I found is about using function key to call the Azure functions from Dynamics 365.

Please if someone knows, please let me know if ouath2.0 is possible and how I can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up a [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerapps-docs/issues/1796) to get update from Microsoft on this topic (as I know this is a challenge for a long time), it is still not positive, but may get some feature in near future. Until then we may have to use HttpClient in plugin directly instead of webhook.

> This is a known challenge which Web Hooks doesn't even attempt to
> address. Your options are limited. So this is a feature request rather
> than a documentation issue.
>
> If you attempt to call such an authenticated service using an
> HttpClient in a plug-in, you have more options. But none of them today
> represent best practices that we would recommend specifically at this
> time, although I see people making them work in community posts.
> Setting a certificate or secret value within the secure configuration
> of the plug-in seems to be the best solution I've seen. But we are
> looking to provide something better.